# S-domain transfer function

Tags: laplace-transform

I always see two common general forms for transfer functions:

$$H_{1}(s)= \frac{1}{\left(s+\omega_{\mathit{p1}}\right)\cdot \left(s+\omega_{\mathit{p2}}\right)}$$

$$H_{2}(s)= \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{s}{\omega_{\mathit{p1}}}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{s}{\omega_{\mathit{p2}}}\right)}$$

Are these two equivalent? I can't derive one form from the other.

[image]

However I know the poles are in the same location.

Comment: $$\mathit{H_1}(s)=\frac{1}{\left(s+\omega_{\mathit{p1}}\right)\cdot \left(s+\omega_{\mathit{p2}}\right)}=\frac{1}{\omega_{\mathit{p1}}\cdot \omega_{\mathit{p2}}\cdot \left(1+\frac{s}{\omega_{\mathit{p1}}}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{s}{\omega_{\mathit{p2}}}\right)}$$

$$\frac{\mathit{H_2}\left(s\right)}{\mathit{H_1}\left(s\right)}=\omega_{\mathit{p1}} \omega_{\mathit{p2}}$$